# GCP : Unable to Initialize Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm unable to Initialize Cloud Shell Editor...
It keep showing Initializing Cloud Shell Editor page only...as per below screenshot.

I'm learning GCP currently through coursers.
I'v tried to Initialize Cloud Shell Editor with Google Chrome, MS Edge, Firefox but issue still persist.
I'v cleared cookie and cache and retried with different account but issue still persist.

Anyone has this issue ? and solution?

[image]

Comment: Hey Junman, 
I have tried to open Cloud shell Editor and mine one works without any issue. Now I can suggest you try the incognito window of chrome and check if this works.

Comment: Hi MustA, thanks for your advice.
After a day, i retried this step with incognito window of chrome mode and i could loading Cloud Shell Editor.
Thank you.

Comment: glad to know it works, putting this as answer and you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on comment, while trying with incognito window in chrome works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use incognito mode, simply allow 3rd party cookies for the site and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using Chrome's Private Window. However, when I tried opening it through Firefox's Private Window, the error disappeared.